# Multiprocessing Pool - too many file descriptors using Pytorch

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, pool

Hello I'm trying to use the [multiprocessing pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) to try and play games simultaneously in a program I'm writing.

Here is a code snipet of what i'm doing:

```
self_play_pool = get_context("spawn").Pool(processes=2)
results = [self_play_pool.apply_async(self.play_game, (False,)) for _ in range(200)]
#self_play_pool.close()
                
for res in results:
     replay_buffer.save_game(res.get())


self_play_pool.terminate()
```

I have tried running it with the ".close()" method on the third line and without it. I also tried the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) pool but it gave me similar errors.

What happens is that after roughly 100 games it crashes giving me either a "broken pipe" error, or a "too many files open" error, like this one:
`BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

For what I was able to gather online, this seems to happen when there are too many processes running since each requires a file descriptor... However I only have 2 processes running simultaneasly.
I also tried to use the "with" context manager but the same happened.

Any help would be apreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Could be somewhere else in your codebase - specifically `play_game`. You might be opening a file and not properly closing it. `f = open(...)` (inproper if you don't close the file afterwards `f.close()`) vs `with open(...) as f:` (closes the file after indent is done.)

Comment: @felipe Thank you for your answer, but I'm not opening files in the rest of my code... Other than a large number of processes, is there any other reason why the program could be creating too many file descriptors/pipes? For example, can the variables I use inside the function influence this at all?

Comment: if you're running under under Linux (or other Unix system) you could try running `lsof` to check which files are open.  you could also try running under `strace` to track what's going on dynamically, but that might be more awkward as it's less obvious where file descriptors are being created

Comment: I have been looking for more answers online, and it looks like that the problem has to do with the fact that I'm using Pytorch in the rest of my code. When in a multi-process enviornment, Pytorch seems to create file descriptors to keep track of Tensors that will be shared... Even though I'm not trying to share any Tensors. I might have to find a different solution... Or just increase my file descriptor limit to a very high number.

Comment: Maybe you could separate out the problematic part of the code into it's own isolated process?

Comment: I found the solution for my problem, if anyone finds this post and wants to know...
If you change the pytorch's sharing strategy with the function
`torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy('file_system')`, it won't create extra file descriptors. It is very important to note that you must run the function both inside the father process and inside each child. I did it by simply putting it as the first line of my `play_game` function, but I think you can achieve the same with the multiprocessing.pool "initializer" argument.

Comment: @GuilhermePalma I'd encourage you to turn this comment into an "answer": https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem, if anyone finds this post and wants to know... If you change the pytorch's sharing strategy with the function `torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy('file_system')`, it won't create extra file descriptors.
It is very important to note that you must run the function both inside the father process and inside each child. I did it by simply putting it as the first line of my `play_game` function, but I think you can achieve the same with the `multiprocessing.pool` "initializer" argument.